# In Outlook, how to open Zoom meeting for an event without opening the event?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2016, zoom-meeting

Is there a way in Outlook to open a Zoom meeting for an event without opening the event?  The Outlook UI is rather clunky.  I am having to open the calendar event just to click on the Zoom link in the body and then remember to close the event later, and it also sometimes asks if I want to save changes when I didn't make any changes.

Is there an easier way to open the meeting?  If its a meeting I am hosting, it shows up in the Zoom app, and 5 minutes before, I get a link in the bottom right corner inviting me to start the meeting.  That feature is awesome!  Basically, I would like to have that for meetings I'm in, even if I'm not the host.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Microsoft clearly knows _how_ to make this easy, but has chosen to do it only for events with a _Teams_ meeting where a handy 'Join online' button appears (e.g. on the reminder popup). This would be super useful for Zoom meetings but sadly I think they are unlikely to do this, for reasons which are not hard to guess.

Answer (score 2):

The compromise that I settled on for now is to also use the Calendar app that is built into Windows 10.  It is a smoother interface and it does not open any annoying modal windows to get to the details of the event.  I can just single click on the event, then single click on the link in the description.  Then later I can just click back on the event.  Overall, while not being perfect, it is quicker and fewer clicks.

Comment: How did you do that?

Comment: @ChristopherOezbek, I'm not sure which part is an obstacle for you so I'll just outline all the steps: press windows button, type calendar and click on that app.  Then click on the Add account button, then choose your work account, which would probably be Office 365, if you're already using outlook.  Then follow the prompts and your calendar should show up fine.  On a side note, there is a revamped version of Outlook which may work better with Zoom links now.  I don't use Zoom at work anymore so I can't easily test it out.

Answer (score 2):

I've sort of accomplished this by adding the reading pane to my outlook calendar view. This way I can click on the event and then click on the zoom link in the reading pane without outlook having to open another window.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is happening because Zoom, like a zillion other apps, neglects to register itself with Windows 10 Apps for Websites. It would be really cool, because like you know, Android and iOS do this really well. Personally, this bugs the crap out of me, just like the OP. At the end of the day I have tons of useless Outlook meetings and Chrome browser tabs open, because to click on the meeting link I have to open the meeting in Outlook, which opens a tab in Chrome, which opens the Zoom client to the right meeting. Clunky.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/web-to-app-linking
https://www.digitalcitizen.life/how-associate-apps-websites-windows-10/

Answer (score 0):

As I know, we do not have options to achieve the zoom link you mentioned above. When you hover your mouse over an event in calendar of your Outlook client, it will show a mini interface to preview your events and this may help you to avoid clicking to open the event.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Unfortunately, that is just a tooltip and it is not clickable, although it would make sense for it to be.